# query distinct value and iterate through results MongoDB C API

Tags: c, api, mongodb

I'm trying to run a query that gets only distinct values from MongoDB. I got the query running and it returns the correct values, however I'm not sure how to iterate over the resulting BSON array using the C API.

here is the code:

```
bson query;
bson out;

bson_init(&query);
bson_append_string(&query, "distinct", "myCollection");
bson_append_string(&query, "key", "someKey");
bson_finish(&query);

if (mongo_run_command( conn, "myDB", &query, &out ) != MONGO_OK) {
   printf("mongo_run_command failed!\n");
   return 1;
}
else {
while(bson_iterator_next(out)){
   bson iterator;
   if (bson_find(iterator, &out, "someKey")) {
      printf("%s\n", bson_iterator_string(iterator));
   }
}
bson_print(&out);
```

The `bson_print(&out)` does print out the correct array, but how can I loop over the array?

The documentation for the C API is very thin on the ground and it doesn't even cover the `mongo_run_command`.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. For those that are looking for a solution here is what worked for me:

```
bson outSub[1];
bson_iterator iterator[1];
bson_iterator iterator2[1];
bson_type type;
const char *value;

// advance to the values array
bson_find(iterator, out, "values");
bson_iterator_subobject_init(iterator, outSub, 0);

bson_iterator_init(iterator2, outSub );
while (bson_iterator_more(iterator2)) {
   type = bson_iterator_next(iterator2);
   value = bson_iterator_string(iterator2);
   if (strlen(value) > 0) {
      printf( "Value: %s\n", value);
   }
}
bson_destroy(outSub);
```

It does pay off to check out the samples that come with the C API :)